# Trying to automate an Ubuntu install but I keep getting some type of error

Tags: boot, 16.04, system-installation, automation, pxe

I'm trying to automate an Ubuntu install for deployment via PXE server but I'm running into an issue. I've used [guide](http://gyk.lt/ubuntu-16-04-desktop-unattended-installation/) to try and configure it but unfortunately I'm running into this error.

[image: error]

Only thing I changed in the guide was this block:

```
label autoinstall
   menu label ^Automatically install Ubuntu
   kernel /install/vmlinuz
   append file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu-server.seed vga=788 initrd=/install/initrd.gz ks=cdrom:/ks.cfg preseed/file=/cdrom/ubuntu-auto.seed quiet --
```

to:

```
label autoinstall
   menu label ^Automatically install Ubuntu
   kernel /casper/vmlinuz
   append file=/preseed/ubuntu-server.seed vga=788 initrd=/casper/initrd ks=/ks.cfg preseed/file=ubuntu-auto.seed quiet --
```

Due to my file paths being different in the ISO I'm using (16.4.06)

Am I doing something wrong or missing something? Let me know if you guys want to see any of the files.

Comment: In your custom block `initrd` is without the `.gz`

Comment: If i put .gz it will say "initrd.gz is missing" since initrd in /casper/ is just initrd without an extension at the end? Unless i'm wrong.

Comment: Ah, ok. I thought it could be the same.